# Further conditional Infile statement task

Tags: sas

The solution provided by Joe was the one most like what I wanted to do, but I have needed to tweak it very slightly on looking at my data. The issue I now have is integrating his syntax into my full infile statement as I am getting a bit lost:

```
data test;
        infile "@myfile" delimiter = ',' MISSOVER DSD lrecl=32767 firstobs=2 ;
        informat EventTypes best32. ;
        informat EventLabels $21. ;
        informat EventID best32. ;
        informat Player_ID best32. ;
        informat ExpandedMinute best32. ;
        informat Second best32. ;
        informat TeamID best32. ;
        informat EndY best32. ;
        informat EndX best32. ;
        informat Y best32. ;
        informat X best32. ;
        informat IsTouch $5. ;
        informat ID best32. ;
        informat Minute best32. ;
        informat Period $10. ;
        informat Type $25. ;
        informat OutcomeType $12. ;
        informat Area1 $25. ;
        informat Area2 $25. ;
        informat ParamVal1 $15. ;
        informat ParamVal2 $15. ;
        informat MatchID best32. ;
        informat MatchDate ddmmyy10. ;
        informat HomeTeamName $100. ;
        informat AwayTeamName $100. ;
        informat FTScore $5. ;
        informat HomeScore best32. ;
        informat AwayScore best32. ;
        format EventTypes best12. ;
        format EventLabels $21. ;
        format EventID best12. ;
        format Player_ID best12. ;
        format ExpandedMinute best12. ;
        format Second best12. ;
        format TeamID best12. ;
        format EndY best12. ;
        format EndX best12. ;
        format Y best12. ;
        format X best12. ;
        format IsTouch $5. ;
        format ID best12. ;
        format Minute best12. ;
        format Period $10. ;
        format Type $25. ;
        format OutcomeType $12. ;
        format Area1 $25. ;
        format Area2 $25. ;
        format ParamVal1 $15. ;
        format ParamVal2 $15. ;
        format MatchID best12. ;
        format MatchDate ddmmyy10. ;
        format HomeTeamName $100. ;
        format AwayTeamName $100. ;
        format FTScore $5. ;
        format HomeScore best12. ;
        format AwayScore best12. ;
        input
        EventTypes
        EventLabels $
        EventID
        Player_ID
        ExpandedMinute
        Second
        TeamID
        EndY
        EndX
        Y
        X
        IsTouch $
        ID
        Minute
        Period $
        Type $
        OutcomeType $
        Area1 $
        Area2 $;
        /*ParamVal $*/
        input @;
        if scan(_infile_,19,',') not in ('Back', 'Defence', 'Forward', 'Left', 'Midfield', 'Right') then 
        input ParamVal1;
        else 
        input ParamVal2 $;
        input 
        MatchID
        MatchDate
        HomeTeamName $
        AwayTeamName $
        FTScore $
        HomeScore
        AwayScore
        ;
        run;
```

As you can see the syntax is not quite correct here and I am not sure how to fix it. What do I need to amend to have a conditional piece of logic in the middle of other fields being input?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic solution to fix your existing code is to add a trailing @ to all but the last INPUT statement.

PROC IMPORT really generates some ugly code. Here is an updated version that will be a little easier to work with.

```
data test;
  infile "@myfile" DLM = ',' TRUNCOVER DSD lrecl=32767 firstobs=2 ;
  length
     EventTypes 8 EventLabels $21 EventID 8 Player_ID 8
     ExpandedMinute 8 Second 8
     TeamID 8
     EndY 8 EndX 8 Y 8 X 8
     IsTouch $5
     ID 8 Minute 8 Period $10 Type $25 OutcomeType $12
     Area1 $25 Area2 $25
     ParamVal1 $15 ParamVal2 $15
     MatchID 8 MatchDate 8 HomeTeamName $100 AwayTeamName $100
     FTScore $5 HomeScore 8 AwayScore 8
  ;
  informat MatchDate ddmmyy10. ;
  format MatchDate ddmmyy10. ;
  input EventTypes -- Area2 @;
  if Area2 not in ('Back', 'Defence', 'Forward', 'Left', 'Midfield', 'Right') then
    input ParamVal1 @
  ;
  else input ParamVal2 @;
  input MatchID--AwayScore ;
run;
```

If you really intended that PARMVAL1 be a number then you need to change how it is defined. In code above variables are **defined** by the LENGTH statement.  In the PROC IMPORT generated code the definition is **implied** by the informat used for that variable in the INFORMAT statement.